# How can I find out what gem is dependent on termios in my Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have updated all of my gems, including to Rails 3.2.8, prior to a new deployment. However, my application is now broken because something is trying to install gem "termios" version 0.9.4.

Apparently, 0.9.4 does not work on any computer or server I own. There are some newer versions, 0.9.6 specifically, but they are not posted in wherever bundler looks for gems.

There are some version on Github, but they have been mysteriously renamed "ruby-termios". Well, some gem in my Gemfile is not looking for ruby-termios. It's looking for termios. Failure.

How can I find out which gem is trying to install this so I can see if it can be whacked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your Gemfile.lock - it has all the gems and their dependencies listed in it. As long as you've been able to install these gems in the past, you'll be able to tell where that dependency is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

The `gem` command will dump out the tree of dependencies for you.

`$ gem dependency`

Or if you want to check just a specific gem.

`$ gem dependency foo`